# why did i got uncaught type error the property value can not set to undefined?

Tags: javascript

Html

```
<div class="container">
<!-- navigation bar-->
<div class="navigator">
<div class="navi_contents">
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" height="100px" width="100px">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="search" placeholder="Search keywords,products and 
brands"></td>
        <td><label for="search" class="fa fa-search" style="cursor: 
pointer;"></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Cart</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Login</li></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

only half html code is given for making sure the class container exists

Javascript

```
var homePage=document.getElementsByClassName('container');
var cartPage = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_container');
var cart_products = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_row');
function product(n){
    homePage.style.display="none";
    cartPage.style.display="block";
    cart_products[0].style.display="block";
    cart_products[n].style.display="block";
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined.
>   browser shows homePage, cartPage is undefined

Comment: Make sure that the `homePage` have an object. For insuring this alert homePage like this `alert(homePage)` after first line

Comment: alert says [object HTMLCollection]

Comment: Answered. If you are getting only one element then use `document.getElementById` because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns array of elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: i reworked the code homePage[0].style.display="none";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `Elements` an array of object so the `homePage` doesn't contain the one element but alot of elements so apply style to this like below.

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
      x[0].style.display="none";
    }
```

It will apply style to first element in array of elements

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `document.getElementsByClassName('container');` with `document.querySelector(".container");` to ***get the first element*** in the DOM that matches the selection, and do the same for other statements.

For more than one element selection, use `document.querySelectorAll("<selector>")` to support other CSS selector types (id, tag, etc.)

Comment: actually its my mistake classname will return as array so i need to use x[0] instead of x to get first element thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

It seems `cartPage` is undefined. You should check if the `cart_container` class name exists in the HTML

Comment: i didnt give the full html. cartPage is exist in my HTML code

Comment: Your answer is not an answer indeed, If you have any doubt about your answer or questioner code please comment first. As like I did see in main  question's comments